# Autostarting applications with XMonad & Ubuntu

Tags: autostart, xmonad

I have recently started to try XMonad and I'm loving it, so far I've managed to set-up xmobar with it.

However, I'm stuck on how to autostart applications, so far I've got both an .xinitrc contains

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb -merge .Xresources
if [ -x /usr/bin/nm-applet ] ; then
   nm-applet
fi

if [ -x /usr/bin/gnome-power-manager ] ; then
sleep 3 
gnome-power-manager
fi


exec xmonad
```

That is it, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: I can see no obvious problem with your `.xinitrc`.  What would you like it to do?  What do you get instead?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an ampersand after anything that needs to run in the background, `nm-applet` and `gnome-power-manager` in your case.  Otherwise it'll just wait there for those to exit before it does anything else.

So your .xinitrc should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb -merge .Xresources
if [ -x /usr/bin/nm-applet ] ; then
   nm-applet &
fi

if [ -x /usr/bin/gnome-power-manager ] ; then
sleep 3 
gnome-power-manager &
fi


exec xmonad
```

Alternatively, you could run xmonad as the window manager inside a Gnome session, and then whatever is set in `gnome-session-preferences` will autostart.  For instructions on how to do that, go here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Using_xmonad_in_Gnome

Comment: As a side note, you probably also want to use `ck-launch-session` on the exec line for xmonad to avoid issue with applications that rely on ConsoleKit.  So that line would look like this instead: `exec ck-launch-session xmonad`.  It doesn't have anything to do with your question, so I didn't include it in the actual answer though.